# Nginx redirect with regex

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Hi I'm having trouble with setting up nginx and redirecting with regex

What's expected is :

**[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** => it redirects to ip 11.11.11.11

**[www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test)** => it redirects to ip 22.22.22.22

**[www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api)** => it redirects to ip 33.33.33.33

I tried this, but idont know what im doing wrong

```
location / {
              rewrite ^/(?:test)/(.*)$ http://22.22.22.22/$1 break;
              rewrite ^/(?:api)/(.*)$ http://33.33.33.33/$1 break;
              proxy_pass              http://11.11.11.11/;
        }
```

And with the config below
When I open **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** first if I try to access **[www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test)** it shows the production site (**[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**)

```
location / {
              proxy_pass              http://11.11.11.11/;
        }

location ^~ /test/  {
              proxy_pass              http://22.22.22.22/;
        }

location ^~ /api/ {
              proxy_pass              http://33.33.33.33/;
        }
```

**Help Please !!**

Comment: nginx location tester: https://nginx.viraptor.info/ Remove the trailing `/` from your location block